# Use rasterio to write 4 band image with rgba photometric

Tags: rasterio, multi-band

I am trying to write a four band rgba tif-file using rasterio. With the following code, I'm able to write four bands.

```
#load data
ras = rio.open(os.path.join(path, file_in))
arr = ras.read()

# load metadata
profile = ras.profile

# update profile
profile.update({'count': 4,
                'photometric': "RGBA",
                'dtype': "int16"})

# create alpha band
alpha = np.where((arr[0]==255) & (arr[1]==255) & (arr[2]==255), 0, 255)

# write file with alpha file
with rio.open(os.path.join(path, file_out), 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(arr[0],1)
    dst.write(arr[1],2)
    dst.write(arr[2],3)
    dst.write(alpha,4)
```

But the bands aren't interpreted in the correct manner:
[image]

Is there a way to solve this in rasterio? For now I'm working around using gdal from the command line:

```
gdal_edit -colorinterp_1 red -colorinterp_2 green -colorinterp_3 blue -colorinterp_4 alpha file.tif
```